# Mapping DTO with circular self dependency

Tags: java, spring, jpa, dependencies, mapper

I have a entity user with self dependency. When i Map this entity to DTO I have the problem of circular dependency. .
User.class:

```
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;
   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @JsonBackReference
   @ManyToMany(
   private List<User> friedns_of = new ArrayList<>();


   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
           mappedBy = "followers")
   private List<User> friends = new ArrayList<>();
```

UserMapper method in UserMapper:

```
    public static UserResponse toUser(User user) {
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        userResponse.setId(user.getId());
        userResponse.setFollowers(user.getFollowers().stream().map(UserMapper::toUser).toList());
        userResponse.setFollowing(user.getFollowing().stream().map(UserMapper::toUser).toList());
        return userResponse;
    }
```

When i run the method toUser() I get stackOverFlowError exception caused by the infinite circular dependency. Any advise how to solve this?

Comment: I believe this line ".map(UserMapper::toUser)" is your problem , You have method reference to the same method which will indeed result in stackoverflow error

Comment: Snip: editing out a misunderstanding of the data. Somewhere there needs to be some logic which checks "this user is already mapped before".

Comment: @Gimby could i see an example please?

Comment: I need a hint to solve this

Answer (score 1):

One way to resolve this is to model the 'follows' relationship as a separate entity:

```
@Table(name="user_followers")
public class Follows {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "follower_Id")
   private User follower;

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "user_id")
   private User user;
}
```

Then you could give your user two one-to-many lists of these entities:

```
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;       

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_id")
   private List<Follows> followers;       

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "follower_Id")
   private List<Follows> following;

}
```

EDIT: instead of the id field in Follows you could use the user_id and follower_id as a composite primary key using @Embeddable. Omitted here for brevity. See here for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a DTO of `UserResponse`, you are on the right path towards a correct solution. My suggestion would be to avoid `@ManyToMany` on an entity level, and manage followers on a service level.

This means you will have to split relation ManyToMany join column into a separate entity, such as `UserFollowsEntity` with fields `userId` and `followsUserId`. Then remove `followers` and `following` lists from your User entity entirely.

Now when creating `UserResponse` in a service, you will have to

1. Select the actual user from repository – `userRepository.findById(userId)`
2. Select followers – `userFollowsRepository.findByFollowsUserId(userId)`
3. Select following – `userFollowsRepository.findByUserId(userId)`

It is a good practice to try and avoid bidirectional in entities relationships entirely if possible.

EDIT: This will give you two lists: followers and following. You will probably want to know their user names, so what you can do is to merge followers and following lists into one, then extract all user ids from that list. Then query user repository with a list of those IDs, and just attach the required user information to your response model.

Yes it does sound like a bit more work compared to the seeming simplicity of utilizing JPA annotations, but this is the best way to avoid circular dependency as well as decouple the Follower functionality from your user entity.